# How to use different versions Nodejs for different react projects in Windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm currently using NodeJS 10 for my current react project but my 2nd react project is not compatible with node 10 and I need to use node 8 version but when I downloaded node 8 version and run msi file, it saying latest version is already installed on my machine and then end the installation.

I'm using windows.

How can I use two different node version on the same machine?

Comment: Hi Kirk and Mayank, I am using windows systems and you guys pointed me to non windows answer and wasted my time , you guys should clarify before doing anything blindly

Answer (score 3):

Use NVM (Node Version Manager) - Simple bash script to manage multiple active node.js versions.

[Here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) you can find more details.

[For Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: I have install NVM but when I run nvm -v command in my terminal it saying
 -bash: nvm: command not found
what is the reason ?

Comment: Not sure about the exact problem but could you please remove nvm completely and re-install again